# TWAINDSM под x64

Tags: c#, x86-64

Функция

```
[DllImport("TWAINDSM_64.dll", EntryPoint = "#1")]
public static extern TwainResult DsmIdentity([In, Out] Identity origin, IntPtr zeroPtr, DataGroup dg, DataArgumentType dat, Message msg, [In, Out] Identity idds);


Message.GetDefault = 0x0003;
var result = DsmIdentity(applicationId,IntPtr.Zero,DataGroup.Control,DataArgumentType.Identity,Message.GetDefault,defaultSourceId);
```

Выдает флаг в **result** 0x0001 (Failure) при компиляции в x64 и использовании TWAINDSM(x64).

Однако при использовании TWAINDSM(x86) и компиляции приложения под x86 все проходит на ура, результат **result** 0x0000 (Success ).

Реально ли использовать TWAIN в x64 приложениях вообще?

**UPD: Нашёл костыль с [NamedPipeClientStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream(v=vs.110).aspx)**

1. Сделать x86 **приложение1**, которое запускает TWINE и пишет данные по картинке в именованный канал, указанный в параметрах запуска.
2. Создать именованный канал из своего приложения (уже не вахно x64 или x86), и запустить **приложение1** с ключём ID именованного канала.
3. при закрытии **приложения1** получить данные из именованного канала.

Есть ли более простые решения данной задачи?

Comment: Вот обсуждение этой проблемы на форуме твайна: http://twainforum.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10708&sid=e357f897a0530b2057edc49eb0f2f1b0

Comment: Т.е. я так понимаю никак не использовать x32 либу Twain в 64x приложениях, даже через TWAINDSM?

Comment: Да, вы все правильно поняли.